# How to set progress intervals in Range Seekbar

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

Hai i created a two thumb range seek bar using given example..but now i am facing a problem..
 Now I am  the getting the min and max value part. The next problem is having custom 
 values for the slider in seekbar. Like i want 500,1000,1500.... etc.but according to example code
 it values progressing 1,2,3..etc I am providing the code for  my main class.

source link:   'https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

```
   RangeSeekBar<Integer>seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(1000, 1000000, context);

   seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {

   @Override

  public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue,Integer maxValue) 

  {

  //handle changed range values

  Log.i("", "Price Range Values: MIN=" + minValue + ", MAX=" + maxValue);

  String range = "Price Range:" + minValue + "-" + maxValue;

  price_range.setText(range);
```

Comment: can anyone help for solve my issue

Comment: Another aspect : Why dont you multiply it by 500?

Comment: can u say me how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just elaborating *rentires* idea. So what you need to do is to divide your Min- and Max-Range by 500 and right in your `onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged` you multiply it by 500.

#### Code

```
    int startValue = 1000;
    int endValue = 100000;
    final int factor = 500;
    RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(startValue/factor, endValue/factor, this);
    seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
            minValue = minValue*factor
            maxValue *= factor;
            value.setText(minValue + " : " + maxValue);
        }
    });
```

In order to make it for the user more transparent which range he has selected you should also enable `notifyWhileDragging`. (This ensures that the `onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged` method is called all the time while the user is dragging the `RangeSeekBar`).

```
seekBar.setNotifyWhileDragging(true);
```

Comment: form start value 1000 to 10000 i want to increment by 100 and from 10000 to 200000 i want increment by 500..how can i do that

Comment: Please stop deleting and reposting the same comment over and over again. The task you're asking for is pretty easy to implement - just change the factor depending on the current value of the SeekBar.

Comment: how can i impliment that..from start value 1000 to upto 30000 i want inciment 100 after that factor 500..according to this code now factor incrimenting 500..pls help

Comment: am expecting help from any developers